# How to store the zipkin traces into postgresql database

Tags: java, postgresql, zipkin

I'm using sleuth for generating the trace ids and span ids and I can see the traces through zipkin UI. I need to store these generated traces into postgresql database. Currently it is storing in memory which will lose on zipkin server restart.

By running the following command(for start the zipkin server)

```
java -jar "C:\dump\java\zipkin-server-2.24.1-exec.jar"  --zipkin.storage.type=mysql --zipkin.storage.mysql.host=localhost --zipkin.storage.mysql.port=3306 --zipkin.storage.mysql.username=myusername --zipkin.storage.mysql.password=mypassword --zipkin.storage.mysql.db=zipkin
```

I can store the zipkin traces into mysql. Zipkin supports storing traces to mysql, cassandra and elasticsearch.

Is there any for storing the traces into postgres?